# Make master branch clean after mistakenly doing a squash merge

Tags: git, merge

Our team has been working on `develop`, doing occasional PRs into `master`. A couple of months ago we have done a PR and used squash merge (lack of knowledge on what the effects will be) to get changes of `develop` into `master`. This commit has been pushed.
The team has continued working on `develop` for a few months now and now we are 400+ commits ahead on `develop`. According to compare, `master` has one commit that's not on `develop`: the squash merge.

Here's what I understood how our tree looks like:

```
---X---------------S  <-- master
  / \             
-     ---A---B---C-----D1---D2 ... Dn  <-- develop
```

`S` being the squash merge of `A`, `B` and `C`.

Now when trying to merge `develop` into `master` (or the other way round) we have a lot of conflicts because there have been changes to both branches (albeit starting with the same changes).

What is a good way to get this sorted out? Is there any way to "undo" the squash merge and go back to a "good" state (eg: `X`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
-M1--X---------------S  <-- master
    / \             
-D1     ---A---B---C--  <-- develop
```

You could do:

- Checkout the commit before the squash
- Perform the merge, without squashing
- Cherry-pick commits that happened after the squash

You should end up with the same content you have now, but the squash replaced with a merge.

That is:

```
git checkout -b master-new M1
git merge D1
git cherry-pick S
```

After this, if `master-new` looks good, then you could backup `master` and replace with `master-new`.
(And pray that nobody minds that you rewrote history.)

Comment: So, I might not have been clear in my example: there was no change after the squashed merge on master, no need for cherrypicking I think (correct me if I'm wrong). The squashed merge is the last commit on master. Is it possible to just remove that?

Comment: @AndrasGaal sure, if there are no commits after the squash then no need for the cherry-pick step. And yes, you *could* just remove the squash, but I suggest to work on a different branch to be safe. So instead of removing the squash, create a new branch starting from the revision before the squash, and work from there.